# How do i write bash shell script for cookie

Tags: bash, shell, http, cookies, session-cookies

Here is bash version
GNU bash, version 5.0.17

Here is the cat -A cookie_jar

```
    ITRUE^I/^IFALSE^I0^ITS01e14722^I01786344cc8175e2661caaa80
    ITRUE^I/^ITRUE^I0^IUserFirmId^I1$
    IFALSE^I/^ITRUE^I0^IPF^IfqTGnM9LIjxqrsn
    IFALSE^I/^ITRUE^I0^BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011   !qaE44xdbX2OjQtdL9Ez/f7vw2P/dxPd2WvZ9xQ==
```

I have a cookie_jar file below is the content of that cookie_jar file

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# https://curl.haxx.se/docs/http-cookies.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

.cn.com TRUE    /   FALSE   0   TS21xx72R2  01786344cc36119d024ed021fc31dad790cc200981f044
.cn.com TRUE    /   TRUE    0   UserxxxId   1we9edfauoefklare
.cn.com TRUE    /   TRUE    0   BUILD0  1teji23jksdfas
#HttpOnly_cn.com    FALSE   /   TRUE    0   BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011  !qaE44xdbX2OjQtdL9Ez/f7vw2P/dxPd2WvZ9xQ==
.cn.com TRUE    /   FALSE   0   TS01dda1cb  01786344cc027084e046d692cedc2bbedc95e2512d8557aedca2
```

I want to have all above cookiename=cookievalue should have in one script and all the cookievalue should show in one line

Tell me How to write a script for above to get cookivalue with there cookiename

Example of i have written some script of it

```
#!/bin/bash
TS21xx72R2="$(grep -m 1 "TS21xx72R2" cookie_jar | awk -F' ' '{print $7}')" 
BUILD0="$(grep -m 1 "BUILD0" cookie_jar | awk -F' ' '{print $7}')" 
TS01dda1cb="$(grep -m 1 "TS01dda1cb" cookie_jar | awk -F' ' '{print $7}')" 
BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011="$(grep -m 1 "BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011" cookie_jar | awk -F' ' '{print $7}')" 
UserxxxId="$(grep -m 1 "UserxxxId" cookie_jar | awk -F' ' '{print $7}')"

echo $TS21xx72R2 $UserxxxId $TS01dda1cb $BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011 $BUILD0
```

Here is the of correct output

```
/cookie.sh: BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011  !qaE44xdbX2OjQtdL9Ez/f7vw2P/dxPd2WvZ9xQ==: No such file or directory
1teji23jksdfas 1we9edfauoefklare 01786344cc027084e046d692cedc2bbedc95e2512d8557aedca2 01786344cc36119d024ed021fc31dad790cc200981f044 ~NP_QA_QF~LOGINQAS0_7011
```

NOTE:- BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011 (when i execute the script i got error that "No such file or directory") but every word is correct in both script and my file

Output im getting correct but only thing is it need to be format in way correct that should be in shell script

New Script will be great helpful

Comment: please update the question with the (wrong) output generated by your script and the (correct) expected output; both of these sets of output should correspond to the sample input you've provided

Comment: I have no idea which strings are considered `cookiename` or `cookievalue`, and while I could **guess**, I don't see anything (from the sample input) that comes close to a count of `14`; hence the request that you update the question with the sets of wrong and correct/expected output; if your code runs without syntax issues then post the output from said run; if you don't know what the correct/expected output should be then how do you know if your code is generating right/wrong output?

Comment: also consider cutting-n-pasting your code (including shebang) into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the suggested edits

Comment: unfortunately the additional details (error/syntax message) just muddies the water even more ... the error message mentions `line 28` but there aren't 28 lines in the script you've provided ... the error messagte mentions a string starting with `"PMV65SXY9tlvO7...` but that string doesn't exist anywhere in your script or the sample input; please review [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, the actual code you're running, matching input and output data

Comment: as mentioned before, cut-n-paste your code into [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) and make the suggested changes; for example: `BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011` is an invalid variable name so `BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011=....` is generating your error

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: If you have accidentally shared confidential information, your boss must contact Stack Exchange to ask for this information to be removed using the DMCA process. You can't vandalise it yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumptions:

- sole objective is to display cookie values on stdout where ...
- `cookie value` is the last entry from any lines that contain the string `TRUE` or `FALSE`
- **NOTE:** it's not apparent (to me) if there's an explicit ordering of the output

One `awk` idea:

```
awk '
/TRUE|FALSE/ { printf "%s%s",pfx,$NF; pfx=" " }
END          { print "\n" }
' cookie_jar
```

This generates:

```
01786344cc36119d024ed021fc31dad790cc200981f044 1we9edfauoefklare 1teji23jksdfas !qaE44xdbX2OjQtdL9Ez/f7vw2P/dxPd2WvZ9xQ== 01786344cc027084e046d692cedc2bbedc95e2512d8557aedca2
```

---

If OP needs to access these later in the script then I'm assuming the cookie name will also be required in which case I'd recommend storing the cookie name/value pairs in an associative array, eg:

```
unset cookies
declare -A cookies

while read -r cname cvalue
do
    cookies[${cname}]="${cvalue}"
done < <(awk '/TRUE|FALSE/ {print $(NF-1),$NF}' cookie_jar)
```

This produces the following array structure/contents:

```
$ typeset -p cookies
declare -A cookies=([BUILD0]="1teji23jksdfas" [TS01dda1cb]="01786344cc027084e046d692cedc2bbedc95e2512d8557aedca2" [TS21xx72R2]="01786344cc36119d024ed021fc31dad790cc200981f044" [UserxxxId]="1we9edfauoefklare" [BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011]="!qaE44xdbX2OjQtdL9Ez/f7vw2P/dxPd2WvZ9xQ==" )
```

From here OP can access the array entries as needed, eg:

```
for i in "${!cookies[@]}"
do
    echo "name = ${i} / value = ${cookies[${i}]}"
done
```

Which generates:

```
name = BUILD0 / value = 1teji23jksdfas
name = TS01dda1cb / value = 01786344cc027084e046d692cedc2bbedc95e2512d8557aedca2
name = TS21xx72R2 / value = 01786344cc36119d024ed021fc31dad790cc200981f044
name = UserxxxId / value = 1we9edfauoefklare
name = BIGipS~NP_QA_QF~LQAS0_7011 / value = !qaE44xdbX2OjQtdL9Ez/f7vw2P/dxPd2WvZ9xQ==
```